# How to create a .app file of my java project to run on mac os

Tags: java, macos

I am new to mac. I have a java project. I created a exe of that project using launch4j for window. Now I need to create a application for mac. I java project contains 5 java classes, also referred to some external jars. I found this site  http://www.centerkey.com/mac/java/. But I struck when I tried to create the executable jar file. While working on window I used the following commands to create the class files and jar file.

To create class files..

```
javac one.java two.java -cp mail.jar;sqlite.jar Mainclass.java
```

To create the jar files for the classes created from the above command

```
jar cvf one.jar one.class
```

I used the same command in mac terminal. But the first command to create the class files doesn't work. Any suggestion....

Comment: Launch the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Mac. Windows and *nix.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. But, I am not intended to download a app from web. I need to create an app for mac osx.

Comment: So the compile command "doesn' work". In what way? Do you get an error message?

Comment: So how do you intend to distribute your app. if not from the web?  Do you intend to deliver it on moon-beams?

Comment: @ njlarsson: I got the following error while running the compile command -bash: dsn.jar: command not found
-bash: imap.jar: command not found
-bash: jxl-2.6.jar: command not found
-bash: mail.jar: command not found
-bash: mailapi.jar: command not found
-bash: smtp.jar: command not found
-bash: sqlitejdbc-v056.jar: command not found
-bash: pop3.jar: command not found

Comment: @ Andrew I need to distribute to my users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Eclipse can create Mac app bundles for Java projects, though i'm not used it and can't say how it works.

Try Export -> Other -> Mac OS X Application bundle

Comment: Thanks corristo. It works. But I refer some folders in my code. That folders are not packed into the resulting application.

Comment: I added the application and folders referred in the code into a single folder. It works fine..

Answer (score 1):

**First thing first, DO NOT USE javapackager**

javapackager is the packaging and signing tool released with JDK 8; When JDK 11 deleted javaFX, javapackager is also deleted as a part of it.

That's why you may encounter below issue when you try to use javapackager:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports javapackager.
```

[image: javapackage error]

I specifically mention it here because there are so many outdated info throughout the internet, cost me so much time going round in circles.

**How I managed to package self-contained Java Application**

1. Use Eclipse to generate runnable JAR file

[image: eclipse]

```
a. Right click your project -> Export.
b. Select Java -> Runnable JAR file.
c. Next.
d. Specify Export destination, e.g. ~/Downloads/jar/HelloSwing.jar .
e. "Library handling" select "Extract required libraries into generated JAR".
f. Finish.
```

2. Use jpackage to package
   [image: jpackage]

Input below command in the termnial:

```
jpackage --type pkg \
 --temp ~/Downloads/temp \
 --name HelloSwing \
 --input ~/Downloads/jar \
 --main-jar HelloSwing.jar \
 --main-class com.cheng.rostergenerator.ui.Main
```

3. Get generated files

[image]

In the current terminal path ~/ , **HelloSwing-1.0.dmg** (51MB) is generated, that is the install file.

Under ~/Downloads/temp, **HelloSwing.app** is generated (125MB), double click to launch the App.

This is just a Hello World project of Java Swing, however, the application image size is a bit daunting.

Anyway, happy coding!

Reference: [jpackage command doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html)

Answer (score 0):

Update on the above: The "Export -> Other -> Mac OS X Application bundle" does not work for me on current Eclipse and Java stuff. Trying to get around this stumbling block I found the following:
https://centerkey.com/mac/java/
I tried their sample for the tutorial, and it worked.